# How to get the sub_level index value of Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a multilevel dataframe `df` :

```
>>> df
                   sales     cash
STK_ID RPT_Date                  
000568 20120630   51.926   42.845
       20120930   80.093   57.488
000596 20120630   22.278   18.247
       20120930   32.585   26.177
000799 20120630    9.291    6.513
       20120930   14.784    8.157
```

And I want to get the value list of sub_level index `'STK_ID'` , which will return a list of `['000568','000596','000799']`.
Is there any direct function to do this (without using `reset_index` and getting the column value)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `index.levels`:

```
In [10]: df1.index.levels
Out[10]: 
[Index(['000568', '000596', '000799'], dtype=object),
 Int64Index([20120630, 20120930], dtype=int64)]

In [11]: df1.index.levels[0]
Out[11]: Index(['000568','000596','000799'], dtype=object)
```

Note you can see the index names:

```
In [12]: df1.index.names
Out[12]: ['STK_ID', 'RPT_Date']
```

*These are discussed in the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object).*

Comment: i aslo found 'df.index.get_level_values('STK_ID')' , it can keep the value order while 'df.index.levels[0]' output the sorted list

Comment: @bigbug You're right, you could use `df.index.get_level_values('STK_ID').unique() == df.index.levels[0]` but levels is stored as is, so it should be faster to access :)

Comment: It's all subjective, but in my quick %timeit benchmark `df.index.levels[df.index.names.index(level_name)]` got 6.69 µs per loop where `df.index.get_level_values(level_name).unique()` got 128 ms per loop.  Thus grabbing the index levels directly is over 19000X faster for my case. (my DataFrame has ~5 million rows which I assume takes time to parse in the `unique()` method)

Comment: @flutefreak7 it's always worth doing the timings :) - the reason is this is so much faster is: `df.index.get_level_values(level_name)` has to be constructed (from levels) then unique applied so it's at least `O(2n)` in number of rows... compared to IIUC O(1).